# How can I show data clustering after building a Convolutional Variational Autoencoder?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, autoencoder

I am brand new to Machine Learning, and just followed [Tensorflow Convolutional Variational Autoencoder Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae) using my own dataset instead of the MNIST set. I was able to successfully display the 2D latent space, but now I want to more explicitly show the clustering of data. How can I use my CVAE to show that there are, for example, 10 distinct clusters for the MNIST data?

Answer (score 0):

You can plot the latent space points and color them according to their digit (assigning a different color to each digit), like this:

[image] ([source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.10599.pdf))